# HTML - A href with popup

Tags: php, html

I have two buttons like this:

```
<?php
<td>
<a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aRSCSSDesign'>Updatestatus</a>
<a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aRCSSDesign'>Delete status</a>
</td>
?>
```

How can I add a popup message to the "Delete status", and ask for "Are you sure you want to delete this?", and if user press "OK", I set the delete code there? Something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm

Comment: are you taking about modal form?

Comment: @Umair Just a simple OK/Cancel popup. Something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm

Comment: check the below answer

Answer (score 0):

```
?php
 $id_one = 1;
 $id_two = 2;
echo "
<td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href='delete.php?id=".$id_one."'>Updatestatus</a>
<a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href='delete.php?id=".$id_two."'>Delete Status</a>
<td>

";
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot the add the full code, sorry. Can you please take a look at my updated question? :)

Comment: did u check my answer?

Comment: Yes, but not sure how that will be when I am using a `a href` inside `php` code.